# How do I figure out which extension or service is making a VS Code Helper process use 100% CPU?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every so often the fans on my MacBook Pro start revving up and certain things in VS Code stop working, such as indentation and autocomplete etc.

When this happens I use [Alfred App](https://www.alfredapp.com/) to figure out which process is causing an issue and it's usually one or more of the *Code Helper* processes launched by VS Code. Sometimes they'll a couple of them using way over 100% of the CPU. I kill the processes and then VS Code prompts me that the extension host has quit and to restart it. Once I do that the extensions start working again as normal. And then the whole thing repeats, just not all the time. For instance I'm writing this message now and Code is fine and not doing anything.

I'm wondering how do I debug this and figure out whether it's Code itself or an Extension causing the issue? If so how do I find out which extension it is?

Comment: Not an answer - but I saw CPU spikes lowered after uninstalling 'Version Lens 1.0.0' plugin.

Comment: Thanks @Kisanagaram, I'm not a user of Version Lens

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Process Explorer is builtin in vscode.
It can be opened using menu by going Help => Open Process Explorer

Comment: Thanks @rayees - this is the same info that's on the link gama11 posted in the comments above but helpful for other none the less 